# How can I use Google Translate so that the translation doesn't change person names?

Tags: google-translate

When I have some texts to translate, I notice that sometimes, [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) messes up person names. E.g.:

> The interview went well. Cherry is good.

[becomes](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=The%20interview%20went%20well.%20Cherry%20is%20good):

> L'entretien s'est bien passé. La cerise est bonne.

which is not good because the person name "Cherry" was changed into "La cerise" (not to mention that "est bonne" would certainly warrant a trip to the HR). "La cerise" means "The cherry" (the fruit).

[image]

How can I use Google Translate so that the translation doesn't change person names?

I asked on https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/312/109 but the question got closed. [Wicket](https://genai.stackexchange.com/users/12/wicket) suggested a great answer (adding `_` around the person names), but I did notice a few cases where the underscore solution didn't work (it worked in >90% of cases I've tried though). Also it's a bit annoying to have to add `_` around the person names. If the solution works for any named entities, that'd be even better.

Comment: This is tough, because I assume you want an accurate translation too. If Google Translate doesn't recognize that "Cherry" is an adult human woman, the rest of the sentence might not be accurate in languages with (grammatical) gender. What languages do you want to translate to?

Comment: @Laurel Thanks, I translate into many languages.  I'm ok if the translation is imperfect.

Comment: I don't see how this can be addressed without some of the techniques in the duplicate target.. The capitalization cue for the proper noun is lost being the first word in an otherwise grammatically sound sentence.